# Who should catch my $_POST data: controller or model?

Tags: php, post, model-view-controller

### My question

I'm unsure about the handling of $_POST data in a MVC architecture: Who should catch the $_POST data: The controller or the model ? Several sources say "skinny controllers, fat models", but same sources also say that a model should be strictly decoupled from the application (and example B clearly shows a "fat" model, but is not decoupled as it directly asks for POST data). For comparison let's see the same thing written in two different ways (example pseudo-code):

**A.) The *controller* grabs $_POST values, passes it as arguments to model**

```
// CONTROLLER
public function createSomething()
{
    $model = new Model;
    $model->createThis($_POST['stuff_from_form']);
}

// MODEL (expects argument)
public function createThis($stuff)
{
    // and here the model method does whatever it does
}
```

**B.) The *model* grabs $_POST values**

```
// CONTROLLER
public function createSomething()
{
    $model = new Model;
    $model->createThis();
}

// MODEL (expects NO argument, grabs POST data directly)
public function createThis()
{
    $stuff = $_POST['stuff_from_form'];
    // and here the model method does whatever it does
}
```

Comment: Check the accepted answer on this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359818/what-is-the-right-way-to-handle-post-data-in-mvc?rq=1) - should help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller should manage all validation and only pass verified / clean data to your models. The reason for this is that you want to keep your models generic enough for re-use and all access to the models/database should be validated / cleansed before hand.

Also don't use `$_POST` directly if you are using something like CodeIgniter then use their handler `$input->post->('name');` (or similarly for any PHP framework).

Answer (score 1):

I will go with the option **A**.

Because you can able to reuse the code by passing different argument later if needed, instead of going through the function contents and change your variables.

Filtering/Sanitizing your variables before pushing them to model is also a good practice, so models only have to think about the data that recieived.